# some Ext JS 2.3.0 classes do not work on my pc

Tags: extjs

I am new to Ext JS. I am trying to develop with Ext JS 2.3.0. I downloaded the BoxSelect extension from http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthre...acebook-s-one) but it doesn't seem to work on my pc. I also realised that the Ext.app.SearchField class does not work on my pc as well. Does any one have any ideas as to why this is happening?
Thanks.

Comment: If you are developing a new application. Why are you using such an old version?

Answer (score 0):

Try with download of the whole set up so that  no need of different js file for different activity in ExtJs.    http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/ . Even I am new to all this and i am accessing through apache server. Also check with declaration of same files. Please also see version of JS.